How can I bypass the limitation of a parameterless constructor with generic types?
I'm trying to write a telegram bot on asp.net using Dependency Injection.
I have several classes - BotController:
public class BotController : Controller
{
    private TelegramBotClient _bot = Bot.GetTelegramBot();
    private UpdateDistributor<CommandExecutor> _updateDistributor = new UpdateDistributor<CommandExecutor>();

    public BotController()
    {
        BotOptions.SetOptions();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async void Post(Update update)
    {
        if (update.Message == null) 
            return;

        await _updateDistributor.GetUpdate(update);
    }
}

When trying to create an UpdateDistributor<CommandExecutor>, I get the following error:

Error CS0310: 'CommandExecutor' must be a non-abstract type and have a public parameterless constructor to be used as a parameter 'T' in a generic type or method 'UpdateDistributor'

Class UpdateDistributor<T>:
public class UpdateDistributor<T> where T : ITelegramUpdateListener, new()
{
    private Dictionary<long, T>? _listeners;

    public UpdateDistributor()
    {
        _listeners = new Dictionary<long, T>();
    }

    public async Task GetUpdate(Update update)
    {
        long chatId = update.Message.Chat.Id;
        T? listener = _listeners.GetValueOrDefault(chatId);
    
        if (listener is null) 
        {
            listener = new T();
            _listeners.Add(chatId, listener);
            await listener.GetUpdate(update);
            return;
        }

        await listener.GetUpdate(update);
    }

    public async void AddListener(Update update,T listener)
    {
        _listeners.Add(update.Message.Chat.Id,listener);
    }
}

And class CommandExecutor:
public class CommandExecutor : ITelegramUpdateListener
{
    private List<ICommand>? _commands;
    private IListener? _listener = null;
    private IServiceProvider? _serviceProvider;

    public CommandExecutor(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;

        var subsRepos = _serviceProvider.GetService<IRepository<UserSubscription>>();
        var servRepos = _serviceProvider.GetService<IRepository<BotService>>();

        if (subsRepos == null || servRepos == null)
            return;

        _commands = new List<ICommand>
                        {
                            new StartCommand(subsRepos),
                            new ServicesCommand(servRepos, subsRepos),
                            new RemoveKeyboardCommand(),
                            new RegisterCommand(this)
                         };
    }

    public async Task GetUpdate(Update update)
    {
        if (_listener == null)
        {
            await ExecuteCommand(update);
        } 
        else
        {
            await _listener.GetUpdate(update);
        }
    }

    private async Task ExecuteCommand(Update update)
    {
        if (update.Message is null)
            return;

        Message message = update.Message;

        if (_commands is null)
            return;

        foreach (var command in _commands)
        {
            if (command.Name == message.Text)
            {
                if (_listener != null)
                {
                    await _listener.GetUpdate(update);
                    break;
                }

                await command.Execute(update);
            }
        }
    }

    public void StartListener(IListener newListener)
    {
        _listener = newListener;
    }

    public void StopListen()
    {
        _listener = null;
    }
}

If I write a constructor without parameters, then the logic breaks.
Can I write something like:
public class UpdateDistributor<T> where T : ITelegramUpdateListener, new(IServiceProvider provider). 

I apologize if I described my problem vaguely

Use a factory function (or class for DI) instead of new T() -- or, perhaps better, let DI provide the T instance, satisfying its dependencies.

You could use HttpContext.RequestServices property, which also is of type IServiceProvider.
Then you can use that to resolve needed services, but it should be used in the method, during HTTP request, not in constructor, where HttpContext will be null.
